# Unable to click on checkboxes using Robot Framework and selenium2library

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I used 3 different waits purposely to locate the element (a checkbox) on the page as shown below and they get passed. After that I click on that same element which also gets passed.

[image]

Now my question is if the **click element** method gets passed then why does **Checkbox should be selected** fails because in click element method I am clicking on that checkbox only!!

[image]

**HTML screenshot.**

[image]

I have tried this clicking on checkbox multiple times using various strategies but it fails every time. Please help and suggest some solution!!

Code I wrote:

```
`  sleep  2
  wait until page contains element  id_service_levels_0
  wait until element is enabled  id=id_service_levels_0
  wait until element is enabled  id=id_service_levels_0
  page should contain element  id=id_service_levels_0


  click element  id=id_service_levels_0
  checkbox should be selected  id=id_service_levels_0
```

`

Comment: Have you tried `Select Checkbox    id=id_service_levels_0` or alternatively `${element}    Get Webelement    id=id_service_levels_0` and then `Click Element    ${element}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with JavaScript executor as given below.

`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
               js.executeScript("document.getElementById('id_service_levels_0').click()");`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to write it exactly , because writing the command as you said is giving an error (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dulbrjqdncvpf0v/Screenshot%202017-06-12%2023.21.53.png?dl=0). and using command `Execute Javascript document.getElementsById('id_service_levels_0').click()` is giving error `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: document.getElementsById is not a function`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try again and let me know. It is not getElementsById and it is getElementById.--singular

Comment: That solved thanks, though How can I know when to use Javascript or when to use other functions?

Comment: Some webpage, mostly the check boxes elements. You can't directly interact with them. Then you try with JavaScript other elements you can go with out JavaScript.